# Linq like functions for PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

I just recently started looking at the asp.net and saw that objects can be mapped using the entity framework then the objects can be searched using linq to pull up specific records within a object/model.

Now is there an equivalent to linq in php?  Something to search a object that has been filled say by `PDO::Fetch_Class`?

```
$mappedobj = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'person');
// is there an easy way to search $mappedobj say by a person_id?
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout phplinq and plinq(not parallel linq in dot net. pls refer link below). They have the same functionality as linq.

PHPLIINQ: http://phplinq.codeplex.com/
PLINQ: http://plinq.codeplex.com/